# Efeito do menu dentro da tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Galera, ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse sobre a palavra menu um pequeno menu se abre. Como faço para isso acontecer dentro da propriedade  (linha) da tabela?

```js
   document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}; //não deixa abrir o menu ao clicar

 $('.menu_pai').mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { //verifica se é o botão direito
     $(this).find('.menu').show();//mostra a div filha
    } 
  }); 
  $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.button != 2) {
        $('.menu').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
.menu{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>ID:1</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
    </tr>
   
</table>

<div class="menu_pai">
    Menu
    <div class="menu">
      link1 <br> link2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer que esse menu abra dentro da linha?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente, sugiro editar a pergunta.

Comment: Igor Mello quero que seja assim. ao clicar com o botão direito a div aparece  fora da linha. O complicado e fazer ela aparecer, o posicionamento eu vou arrumar com css.

Comment: @HugoBorges Ao clicar com o botão direito em cima da linha/coluna?

Comment: ao clicar em toda a linha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz da seguinte forma: somente alterei o seu seletor que estava pegando o `document` para `$("tr")` que pega qualquer linha da tabela e adicionei um operador ternário para fazer o teste de qual **botão** do **mouse** foi clicado e executar a ação!

```js
//não deixa abrir o menu de contexto ao clicar com o botão direito
document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}; 

$("tr").mousedown(function(e) {
  $(".menu").html("Link " + (this.rowIndex+1) + "<br> Link " + (this.rowIndex+2));
  (e.button == 2) ? $(".menu").show() : $(".menu").hide();
});
```

```css
.menu{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td>ID:1</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ID:2</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="menu_pai">
    <div class="menu">
      
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Para atender esta sua última dúvida basta adicionar a seguinte linha no Jquery

```
$(".menu").html("Link " + (this.rowIndex+1) + "<br> Link " + (this.rowIndex+2));
```

Comment: muito bom mesmo ;) tenho uma dúvida, como faço para o jQuery verificar automaticamente quanto <tr> tem a tabela, e para cada um abrir uma div pai: exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/0d3ketxk/4/

Comment: @HugoBorges Se a resposta está correta por favor sinalizar como certa para ajudar outros que tenham a mesma dúvida! Dei um **update** na resposta, olha se atende esta tua última dúvida?

Comment: muito bom, esta perfeito, a única com que esta faltando e fazer a div aparecer na mesma posição so cursor do mouse, tem como fazer isso?

Comment: pronto ja editei a resposta, muito obrigado